# Java11 upgrade: Javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

Tags: java

Below are the Java 11 jakarta EE specific dependencies provided in web service project and target platform pom files.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Still getting exception on trying to host the service using `Endpoint.publish()`

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found